# How to embed the content of one post into another site

Tags: posts, embed

I have two websites, and I want to embed the content of one post on one of these sites, into a post in the other site.

I have looked at various plugins but can't find anything that works.

I can embed the entire page with this code:

```
<object data=http://www.pg-mysite.com/squares width="650" height="500"> <embed src=http://www.pg-mysite.com/squares width="650" height="500"> </embed></object>
```

But I only want the content to appear, not the headers, footers, sidebars etc.
Is there a way to get just the post content?

Comment: My thought is the process like yours: I think `<iframe>` with some javascript code or, simple CSS `display:none;` can work with ease.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress generates a large number of RSS feeds. For a single post the URL for that feed is the single post URL plus `/feed/` or `?feed=rss2` if pretty permalinks are off. If you try that you will see the comments feed, though, and not the post itself. To get the post itself add `?withoutcomment=1` or `&withoutcomments=1` and you will get the post content itself. Have your other site request that feed, whether by AJAX or some PHP function like `curl`-- whatever you have available to the requesting site-- and process the XML to display it however you like.